# How do I force a UIWebView to update when it's offscreen?

Tags: iphone

I have a UIWebView that I'm setting to some text and displaying and then hiding, changing the text, and displaying again.  The issue I'm running in to is that when I make the view visible again I see the old text for an instant.  Is there a way to force the UIWebView to show the new text when it displays?

The code is ordered correctly and looks like this:

```
[back assignLabelText:[facts getCurrentFact].answer];
[self doAnimation:back.view andViewToHide:front.view flipRight:YES];
```

Comment: I don't know if it's worth noting or not but the emulator doesn't seem to have any issues with this.  It's only when I'm testing on my iPhone 4.

Comment: what is happening in `getCurrentFact`?

Comment: getCurrentFact is just getting the text to display.  assignLabelText does all of the text assignment.

Comment: What is the source of the text?

Comment: I have a class called fact that contains some preloaded info.  Right now it's just simple stuff like "What's 1+1".  The front view contains the fact's question and the back contains the answer.  It's just a simple flashcard app.

Comment: What is your motivation for using UIWebView? Can you include the code for `assignLabelText`

Answer (score 2):

You should wait until at least the webview's `webViewDidFinishLoad:` is fired before revealing the webview.  Even then there can be some lag, so I add an additional 0.1 second delay before revealing the view.

Answer (score 1):

Call [setNeedsDisplay](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay) on back's view

```
[back assignLabelText:[facts getCurrentFact].answer];
[[back view] setNeedsDisplay];
[self doAnimation:back.view andViewToHide:front.view flipRight:YES];
```

Comment: That still has the lag.  If I were doing something like this in Windows I'd consider calling DoEvents after setting the text to tell the UI loop to run but I can't seem to find anything like that.

Comment: Try adding a delay before doing the animation. What's likely happening is that your animation is saving what the view looks like before the animation and never gives it a chance to render.

Comment: Works brilliantly! Thanks a lot for this tip, i feared the worst that the web view simply couldn't be used in animations, but *phew* they can :)

Answer (score 1):

I made some new functions to do my animations and used a delay of 0.1 to run them via `performSelector`.

It feels like a hack but it works and it takes care of the same issues I was having with UILabels that have their text change.